# Dividing a sorted list

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I have a list of movies and need to group them in both c# (or angular is also acceptable) and css very similary to the image provided here underneath. Any ideas on how to wire the html and c# and how to use the .groupBy() or something similar please ?

This is what I've got so far:

HTML (a list of all my movies in alphabetical order):

```
 <div class="movs">
 <movies-collection movies="::vm.sortedMovies" order-by="name"></movies-collection>
 </div>
```

Typescript:

```
 static id = "MoviesController";

        static $inject = _.union(MainBaseController.$baseInject, [
            "sortedMovies"
        ]);

        static init = _.merge({
            sortedMovies: ["allMovies", (movies: Array<Models.IGov>) => {
                return _.sortBy(movies, "content.name");
            }]
```

All my movies are already sorted alphabteically I just need to with the help of css structure them similarly to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8CP.png)

Comment: The problem here is what, exactly?

Comment: I need to sort all the list again and put a div around each list of alphabet like the image instead of just naming them alphabetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a filter that adds a "$first" property to the movie. If it is the first in a sorted list that starts with the character, then $first would be true.  Bind to $first in your view when you show the character in uppercase.

The following demonstrates this idea:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [
    { title: 'The Godfather' },
    { title: 'Fargo' },
    { title: 'Sniper' },
    { title: 'Terminator'},
    { title: 'Click'},
    { title: 'Cake' },
    { title: 'Frozen' },
    { title: 'Casino Jack' },
    { title: 'Superman' },
    { title: 'The Matrix' }
  ];
});
app.filter('applyFirst', function() {
  return function (movies) {
    for(var i = 0; i < movies.length; ++i) {
      if (i == 0) 
        movies[i].$first = true;
      else {
        if (movies[i].title.toLowerCase()[0] != movies[i-1].title.toLowerCase()[0]) {
          movies[i].$first = true;
        }
        else {
          movies[i].$first = false;
        }
      }
      
    }
    return movies;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy:'title' | applyFirst">
      <h1 ng-if="movie.$first">{{ movie.title[0] | uppercase }}</h1>
      {{ movie.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in css, your code must split the array of movies into an array of letters, each with an array of movies.
You can use **reduce** for that:

```
var groupedMovies = movies.reduce((lettersArray, movie, idx, arr) => {
    var firstLetter = movie[0].toUpperCase();
    if (!lettersArray[firstLetter]) {
        lettersArray[firstLetter] = [movie];
    }
    else {
        lettersArray[firstLetter].push(movie);
    }

    return lettersArray;
}, []);
```

The result will look something like this:

```
[ T: [ 'The Avengers', 'Tower Quest', 'ThunderFist', 'Transformers' ],
  U: [ 'Untamed Bengal Tiger', 'Untamed Giant Panda' ],
  V: [ 'Victorious' ] ]
```

This way you can do a loop on the letters array, and in each do another loop for each movie.

The best practice for that would be to create a directive for a grouped movies, it will receive the letter and the inner array of movies in that letter.